# Load Runner controller : After rampup is attained we see dip in Vusers

Tags: loadrunner, microfocus

Load Runner controller : After Rampup is attained we see a dip in Vusers and then target Vusers are attained. This causes load to fluctuate and response time been affected. What can I look into next?

In screenshot below we can see after target of 1800 users is attained  at 00.50 again Vusers falls back to 1500 users and then ramped up to 1800. This happens in most of the runs from Load Runner.

[image]

Comment: If you do not have an error, then you likely have some coincident times where users are between iterations, causing a temporary drop in number of active users on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by changing the Runtime Settings --> Logs --> Detail Level to Standard

Issue was occurring because Detail Log level was set to Extended.

[image]